# How to add HighScoreSystem to snake.js game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build my own game and i just came across a nice tutorial on a snake.js game that i coded. Me and my friends put up the game on a website but now we want a high score system to go with it. I have looked around the internet but i cant really figure out a way to make it work.

IN SHORT:
How do i add a high score system that keeps track of a players score and adds it to the high score list on the website.

```
<body>
  <canvas width="400" height="400" id="game"></canvas>
  <script src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

this is the html and css, javascript is in the pastebin link. https://pastebin.com/gCjDzBfg

Comment: You save the the scores in a database and then order them by the highest to the lowest. You set the score by your own rules

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a database to store your high score. Each time a game is ended, you can get the score and compare with the high score in the Database. If the player's score is greater than the score in Database you can update it.

Try Firebase RealTime data. 
Please refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write